# Dynamic memory allocation in for loop

Tags: c, malloc, dynamic-memory-allocation

I'm allocating memory using `malloc`:

```
 main()
{
   int *array;
   int i;
   for(i = 0; i<40; i++)
   {
     array = malloc(100 * sizeof(int));
   }
   free(array);
}
```

This should allocate `15.625KB` but if i run this same in `valgrind`, peak memory is `15.92KB`. 
How it comes?

How to free all 40 pointers?

Comment: heap fragmentation probably

Comment: I think more than 400 bytes are allocated i.e. 408 bytes should have been allocated per malloc call. Maybe internal heap data like next/prev pointer?

Comment: Your code contains a bug: you have to keep every pointer returned from malloc and free that pointer individually. You are only freeing the last pointer. This causes a memory leak hold by 39 pointers previously allocated.

Comment: If you are trying to resize the currently allocated memory, you should be using realloc. Malloc will allocate new memory, and as CouchDeveloper stated, the previously allocated memory is no longer accessible in your current code and is therefore, never freed.

Answer (score 4):

`malloc` always allocates a bit more than you asked for, necessary for internal accounting, caused by fragmentation, etc.

At a minimum - the size of each allocated block need to be stored somewhere, often some pointers (e.g. to the next allocated/free block) are also stored, and in some cases (e.g. debug builds) additional debugging information is also stored. Most implementation store as much information as possible in the unallocated space, so only a few bytes (e.g. size) would be stored in each allocated block.

As to fragmentation, many implementations have a minimal allocated size or round up the requested size to maintain some kind of alignment.

Answer (score 1):

Regarding freeing all 40 pointers, you could for example have an array of pointers holding the pointers returned from malloc and go over it at the end of your function.

Something along the lines of:

```
main()
{
   int *arrays[40];
   int i;
   for(i = 0; i<40; i++)
   {
     arrays[i]=malloc(100 * sizeof(int));
   }

   for(i = 0; i<40; i++)
   {
     free(arrays[i]);
   }
}
```

Comment: sorry,i cant able to understand C++

Comment: Switched to a C example

Answer (score 1):

free (array) should be inside the loop to free all pointers instead of the last one only.

Answer (score 0):

When you call malloc(),The amount of memory actually used is slightly more than what is requested.This extra includes information that records how big the block is, where is next free block available etc.

This extra information is the reason so that free() function knows how much to free.